# Assignment from Incompatible Pointer Types

Tags: c, structure, unions

Here's the following problem, Im getting Asisgnment from incompatible pointer types in the next code:

TO resume this to you the line 43 goes as follows:

```
  aux->sig=nodo;
```

Line 60 :

```
 aux2=aux2->sig;
```

Basically im getting every error in "aux2"

Whats is causing this? And if you could explain this to me, Im a student and Im basically new to programming.

```
proyecto2mod.c: In function ‘agrega_nombre’:
proyecto2mod.c:43: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
proyecto2mod.c:60: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
proyecto2mod.c: In function ‘busca_cliente’:
proyecto2mod.c:105: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
proyecto2mod.c: In function ‘ordena’:
proyecto2mod.c:118: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
proyecto2mod.c:119: error: request for member ‘nombre’ in something not a structure or  union
proyecto2mod.c:119: error: request for member ‘nombre’ in something not a structure or union
proyecto2mod.c:120: error: request for member ‘direccion’ in something not a structure or union
proyecto2mod.c:120: error: request for member ‘direccion’ in something not a structure or union
proyecto2mod.c:121: error: request for member ‘num_cliente’ in something not a structure or union
proyecto2mod.c:122: error: request for member ‘ant’ in something not a structure or union
```

...
And So on.

Heres the Codes:

MAIN CODE

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "clientes.h"
#include "ventas.h"
extern void agrega_nombre(ApLista1 inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo, ApLista1 aux2);  
extern void busca_cliente(ApLista1 inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo, ApLista1 aux2,    ApLista2 inicioventas, ApLista2 auxventas, ApLista2 nodoventas, ApLista2 aux2ventas);
extern int ordena(ApLista1 inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo,ApLista1 *aux2);
int main(void)
{
int menu=0;

 //LISTA1 *aux2,*nodo;
 ApLista1 inicio, aux, nodo, aux2;
 ApLista2 inicioventas, auxventas,nodoventas,aux2ventas;

inicio=NULL;
nodo=malloc(sizeof(LISTA1));
aux=malloc(sizeof(LISTA1));
inicioventas=NULL;
nodoventas=malloc(sizeof(LISTA2));
auxventas=malloc(sizeof(LISTA2));

system("clear");
while(menu!='6')
 {
    //funcion void carga_datos();
  printf("TIENDA DEPARTAMENTAL\n\n\n");
  printf("1. Agregar a un Cliente.\n2. Agregar una venta.\n3. Buscar Cliente. \n4.     Borrar Cliente. \n5. Borrar una venta. \n6. Salir.");
  printf("\n\nElige una opcion: "); 
  scanf("%d", &menu);
  switch(menu)
{
case 1:
  system("clear");
  printf("opcion1\n");

  agrega_nombre(inicio, aux,nodo, aux2);
  menu=0;
  break;
case 2:
  system("clear");
  printf("opcion2\n");

  ///lo mismo que agrega_cliente pero utilizando la lista de ventas.
  menu=0;
  break;
case 3:
  system("clear");
  printf("opcion3\n");
  busca_cliente(inicio,aux,nodo,aux2,inicioventas, auxventas, nodoventas,  aux2ventas);
  menu=0;
  break;
case 4:
  system("clear");
  printf("opcion4\n");
  //borra_cliente(inicio,aux,nodo,aux2,inicioventas, auxventas, nodoventas,   aux2ventas);
  menu=0;
  break;//
case 5:
  system("clear");
  printf("opcion5\n");
  //Lo Mismo que borra cliente pero en la lista de ventas solamente.
  menu=0;
  break;
case 6:
  system("clear");
  printf("Adios!\n");
  exit(1);
  menu=0;
  break;
 }
   }
}
```

Functions that go in main:

```
 void agrega_nombre(ApLista1 *inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo, ApLista1 aux2)
{

 FILE *clientes;
 int pops=0, sanders=0;
 char aux_char[80];


  system("clear");
 clientes=fopen("clientes.txt", "a+");
 //fseek(clientes, 0L, SEEK_END);



if(nodo==NULL)
 {
   printf("No hay memoria\n");
   exit(1);
 } 
  printf("NOMBRE:");
  scanf("%s", nodo->nombre);
  printf("DIRECCION:");
  scanf("%s",nodo->direccion);
  printf("NUMERO DE CLIENTE:");
  scanf("%d", &nodo->num_cliente);

  if(inicio==NULL)
{
  (*inicio)=nodo;
  (*inicio)->sig=NULL;
  (*inicio)->ant=NULL;
  aux=(*inicio);
}
  else
{
  aux->sig=nodo;
  nodo->ant=aux;
  aux=nodo;
  nodo->sig=NULL;
}

  pops++;

  aux2=(*inicio);

  while(aux2!=NULL)
{
  fprintf(clientes, "%s\n", aux2->nombre);
  fprintf(clientes, "%s\n", aux2->direccion);
  fprintf(clientes, "%d\n", aux2->num_cliente);
  puts(aux2->nombre);
  puts(aux2->direccion);
  aux2=aux2->sig;
}


  aux2=aux;
  do
{
  puts(aux2->nombre);
  aux2=aux2->ant;
}
  while(aux2!=NULL);
  fclose(clientes);
 }

 //Funcion Busqueda
 void busca_cliente(ApLista1 inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo, ApLista1 aux2, ApLista2   inicioventas, ApLista2 auxventas, ApLista2 nodoventas, ApLista2 aux2ventas)
   {
char nombrebusqueda[80];
int numclienteprueba;
inicio=NULL;

printf("Dame el nombre del cliente a buscar\n");
scanf("%s",nombrebusqueda);
aux2=aux; 
while(aux2!=NULL)
  { 
    printf("Entramos al While Aux2");
    if((strcmp(nombrebusqueda,aux2->nombre))==0)
      {
    printf("Encontramos BAM");
    puts(aux2->nombre);
    ////////Buscamos la venta
    aux2ventas=auxventas; 
    while(aux2ventas!=NULL)
      {
        numclienteprueba=aux2ventas->num_clienteventas;
        if(numclienteprueba==aux2ventas->num_clienteventas)
          {
        printf("Wow");
        ///Aqui ensenamos las ventas que ha tenido el cliente y la i   informacion de la estructura.
          }
        aux2ventas=aux2ventas->sigvent;
      }
    ////////////
      }
    aux2=aux2->sig;
  }
   }

 //Funcion Ordena



     int ordena(ApLista1 inicio, ApLista1 aux,ApLista1 nodo,ApLista1 *aux2)
 {
char pruebaman[80],probaman[80];//nombres
char pruebadireccion[150],probadireccion[150];//direccion
int pruebanum_cliente,probanum_cliente;//numero de cliente
aux2=aux;
strcpy(pruebaman,aux2->nombre);
strcpy(pruebadireccion,aux2->direccion);
pruebanum_cliente=aux2->num_cliente;
aux2=aux2->ant;

do
  {

    strcpy(probaman,aux2->nombre);

    if(pruebaman[0]<probaman[0])
{
  strcpy(pruebaman,aux2->nombre);
  strcpy(pruebadireccion,aux2->direccion);
  pruebanum_cliente=aux2->num_cliente;
  aux2=aux2->sig;
  strcpy(aux2->nombre,probaman); 
  strcpy(aux2->direccion,probadireccion);
  probanum_cliente=aux2->num_cliente;    
}
  strcpy(pruebaman,aux2->nombre);
  strcpy(pruebadireccion,aux2->direccion);
  pruebanum_cliente=aux2->num_cliente;

  aux2=aux2->ant;


  printf("Ciclo\n\n");

}
while(aux2!=NULL);
aux2=aux;
strcpy(pruebaman,aux2->nombre);
aux2=aux2->ant;
strcpy(probaman,aux2->nombre);
if(pruebaman[0]<probaman[0])
 ordena(inicio,aux,nodo,aux2);
 }
```

Structures:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  typedef struct clientes{
  char nombre[80];
   char direccion[150];
  int num_cliente;
  struct cliente*sig;
  struct clientes *ant;
  struct ventas *vent;
  }LISTA1;
  typedef struct clientes *ApLista1;
```

Second Structure:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  typedef struct ventas{
  int num_clienteventas;
  char nombre_producto[150];
  int precio;
  int unidades;
  char fecha[11];
  struct ventas *sigvent;
  struct ventas *antvent;
  }LISTA2;
  typedef struct ventas *ApLista2;
```

Answer (score 4):

In `int ordena()`, you define `aux2` as an `ApLista1*`, which is basically a `struct clientes**`. You then try to assign it into `aux`, which is defined as `ApLista1 aux`, namely a `struct clientes*` - note the missing star.

`aux2` being a pointer to a pointer to a struct, it's clear why calls like `aux2->nombre` are not compiling. The solution is to either define `aux2` as `ApLista1`, or dereference it when needed.

Oh, and as a side note - IMO, hiding `*`s behind `typedef`s is not a good practice. It doesn't help you type less, and it makes the code less readable - and as in this case, more error prone.

Comment: +1 on including `*` in the typedef.  Doing so often results in confusing code, unless the type clearly indicates it's a pointer like Microsoft's `lp` prefix, or using `ptr` or `handle` somewhere in the name.